# Required field error in Billing Information

Tags: checkout, billing, required

We always seem to be having issues with the **checkout**.

Customer cannot get past the **billing information** section, they **click continue** and it keeps saying **required field**, and it won't let them go any further, however, everything is filled in correctly.

How do I fix this, please?

Comment: it may be some fields are hidden or display none fields and fields are required. please check with inspect element

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with the attributes. You must remove this attribute from the database and remove it from the `InstallData.php` and `UpgradeData.php` scripts.